# "invisibility of unstable equilibria

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems

While looking at some basic dynamical systems examples (first 3 chapters of Strogatz), a teacher told me that in real life the computer doesn't actually see unstable equilibria. Why is that? I have an idea but would like a more detailed answer

Comment: Is "unstable" in this context everything that is not stable or just the other end from "stable", points around which the system is expanding in all directions?

Comment: In this case it would be the latter. What do you mean by the former? can you give an example?

Comment: One could also say that saddle points are quickly passed-by, in non-trivial systems the probability to get on and stay on a stable manifold of such a point is practically zero. Repelling points of course to not have any path towards them, exact or in floating point.